# Casting object to declared type in drools RHS

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I've got my declared type as follow:

```
declare MyType
 myField: String
end
```

Now I'm getting a list of myType from a globals. I need to cast the object that is coming from the globals to MyType.
Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use your declared classes outside your DRL files, then I would recommend you to declare them as Java classes.

There is a way to work with these type of objects in Java and that is done using reflection through the `KieBase.getFactType(String package, String name)` method.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I need to use these objects inside DRLs. I only need to load a set of facts as initialization. So I would load them with a global interface using object created with inputFactType.newInstance(). Is this wrong?

Comment: Is not wrong, just remember that you will need to add some hard-to-read code and use reflection behind the scenes.